# Libgdx Actions interpolation Fadeout

Tags: java, android, libgdx, interpolation

In `libGDX` there is a simple fade `Interpolation` that speeds up towards the end of the action animation. But what I am looking for is the reversed of it, it needs to start fast and slow down near the end. Is there a `Interpolation` function for that or how can I create this effect myself?

Currently i'm directly just initiating the action from the actor.

```
actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(currentTouch.x - actor.getWidth() / 2,
 currentTouch.y - actor.getHeight() / 2,
 .2f,
 Interpolation.fade));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `Interpolation.bounceIn.apply(current_position, target_position, smoothness)` to achieve this effect. Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtU4fBauW8c).

**Edit** I found the answer on their site

```
MoveToAction action = Actions.action(MoveToAction.class);
action.setPosition(x, y);
action.setDuration(duration);
action.setInterpolation(Interpolation.bounceOut);
actor.addAction(action);
```

***(I haven't tested it !!)***

Take a look at the full tutorial [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)

Comment: Thanks, could you demonstrate here how I would use that within the addAction method for a complete answer? `actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(currentTouch.x - actor.getWidth() / 2, currentTouch.y - actor.getHeight() / 2, .2f, Interpolation.bounceIn.apply(2,2,2)));` does not even compile. Still have to watch the vid but a complete answer here would benefit.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Check it out.

Comment: `bounceOut` does not do what I want. It bounces, I need a powerfull start that fades out smoothly. It looks somewhat like `pow2Out` in the video but still not exactly what i want. Likewise i cannot seem to combine `Interpolation.bounciIn.apply(float,float,float)` with `setInterpolation`.

Comment: `Interpolation.bounceIn.apply(current_position, target_position, smoothness)` is out of scene2d, try this format `action.setInterpolation(Interpolation.TYPE);`

Comment: You could use `Interpolation.fade` or  `Interpolation.pow4out` or ` `Interpolation.pow5out`, it depends of what do you need

Comment: I somewhat got the effect I want, indeed the `powOuts` are what i actually need, not fade since that is reversed. But somehow I still cannot get the power at start and a very slow fade to the end. I am trying to mimic a 3D effect of shooting an object away from the camera. I am using two actions: `moveTo` that needs to fade out very softly and `scaleBy` that needs to be linear or fade slightly.